# Is dividing a program into multiple files heavier than using one big file?

Tags: c, compilation, embed

I am currently developping an embedded application, and the problem is that I have reached a point where the whole app is actually too heavy for the RAM.

So I am asking myself this question: Would my compiled program be lighter if I refractored some the files into one big file?

Thanks.

Comment: No. The amount of code and global data will at least be the same. You may need to redesign your application to be lighter.

Comment: Assuming bare-metal, mainstream microcontroller application. To save RAM, focus on removing common beginner mistakes such as using the heap, using stdio.h or using float numbers. If you find any of these in your program and remove it, it will likely free up vast amounts of RAM.

Comment: All I can think of is the pathname would probably be longer with multiple files, but whether relevantly different, who knows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code would be 100% identical in the "big file" and the "many files" approach, the main difference is that addresses of variables and fuctions would be resolved (i.e. padded into the binary) by the linker rather than the compiler. This should normally result in the very same binary.

There are, however, architectures that have "short relative addressing modes" (Motorola 68k is an example) for calls and references, where the "big file approach" could actually result in (slightly) smaller code and data. The compiler cannot normally insert such short addressing modes into modules intended for linking because at compile time it is not known how far away the reference would be in the resulting program.

So, depending on the CPU you are using, you might actually gain a few bytes.

Answer (score 1):

No, not in general.

The source-code organisation doesn't impact the memory use.

It might be possible to refactor the program to use less memory, if you for instance have pieces of functionality that both use significant amounts but never run in parallel, but that's equally doable in a single file. It just requires making the sharing explicit.